# Spotify API redirect URL to local filesystem?

Tags: html, redirect, spotify

I'm trying to write a program for myself using Spotify's api. I have no intention of my software being public, I just need access to my own playlist data. The issue is, in order to actually get this information, I need to go through Spotify's authentication process. Part of this process is a redirect URL which it sends you back to once you've logged on. The issue is, I don't actually have my code/site online, its just on my local file system. How can I open up an html file on my local filesystem using spotify's redirect url?

[image]

Note:
I tried entering a path like I would for a cmd run command such as `C://Users/Me/file.html` but this did not appear to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about how Spotify's API works, but there are two options that I see.

1. For the url, you could use `file:///my-path` but this might not work
2. Use a `localhost` url. An easy way to do this is python's `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

Answer (score 1):

According to Spotify api you can start a server by using nodejs and assigning `http://localhost:8888/callback` in the *white-list* of the api.developer portal

**remember to save after you have added it to the white list**

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I've got it working now, used weebly's custom HTML blocks to do it. +1 anyways though.